# Name of a werewolf novel from the 80's

Tags: story-identification, novel, vampire, werewolf

I was a big reader of the horror paperbacks from the 80's. I read so many that I can't remember specific titles. There's one in particular that I was trying to find or at least get the name of.

The only specifics I remember is that it involves a man and a woman (don't remember if they were married or a couple or what). They move to a town (possibly in the mountains?) and long story short they discover the town is all werewolves (or at least one).

Anyway, the part that really stuck with me was the epilogue where, after they burn the town down (I think)... months (or years later) they are together somewhere else and one of them yells/shrieks...the other comes running in and the first tells the other that they just read that if after killing a werewolf, if it's not buried properly (in consecrated ground)... like when you burn a town down...the werewolf will rise again as a vampire.

Its only one of two novels I read where they make that connection between werewolves and vampires.

Can someone help me out? I've googled werewolf books of the 80's. I even went to some thread somewhere where they listed and showed covers for a lot of those books but so far I cannot find anyone who knows the book I am talking about

Comment: Unfortunately, the bit about werewolves turning into vampires probably is not going to help much, because that's actually lore that goes back to our oldest legends of the two monsters.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

[*Cry Wolf* by Alan Chronister](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/B01N3UMF1O)?

> Former yuppies Rudy Vardon and Evelyn Sangellis think their rustic home in Larksboro is wonderful, but they aren't prepared for the horror that peers from the shadows by day and into their windows at night.
>
> -- [Google Books](https://books.google.com/books/about/Cry_Wolf.html?id=M1melPWS9E0C&redir_esc=y)

> A little town out east is infested with werewolfs. A man and woman move in to write and illustrate children's books. What they find is a nightmare.
>
> -- [Goodreads review](https://www.goodreads.com/book/show/362714.Cry_Wolf)

Comment: Hi, welcome to SF&F.  Could you provide some details to show how this book matches the question?  Maybe add a quote from the epilogue mentioned?

Comment: I have read this one, enjoyed it immensely, and with the exception of burning down the town (there is a barn burned down, similar to the scene in The Howling), seems pretty close. There is a couple involved, writers I believe, and a family, and both discover the small town in a mountainous area, is nothing but werewolves. It also involves the main antagonist werewolf (bastard son of a preacher) being killed as a werewolf, but not beheaded or burned, and rises as a vampire at the end.

Comment: Michael Vinson you are amazing. That indeed was the book. I just bought it. THANK YOU!!!!

Comment: Glad I could help. Enjoy!

Comment: @MikeD Please don't forget to accept this answer (by clicking the checkmark on the left) to mark it as correct :-)